# Combined ExternalID

Tags: externalid

I have fields UserID and RoleID. Combination of these fields are unique. Is it possible make these combination as ExternalID without creating new field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no...............

Comment: Thank you Eric.

What is the best solution in this case?

Comment: On User the UserID is unique so no need to created anything....If this is another object, create an external ID field

Comment: It is another object.
 So I should create an external ID field, which will be the unique combination of UserID and RoleID. isn't it ?

Comment: It won't be unique unless the user you are referencing on the object cannot be on more than one record....

Comment: In my object  User can have several Roles and only  UserID and RoleID pair is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without creating a new field. I usually create a new field called Composite Key or something like that. You can mark that one as an external id. Just make it a text field of width 36 and populate it with the combination of the two fields. This can be done in a trigger or a workflow, whatever suits your situation best.

Note that if you want to use upsert with this field to decide whether it's an insert or update, you have to populate the field before doing the database call.